# IP Address 47.128.16.39 has been going through our site for more than 4 days

Tags: authentication, attacks

This IP address has been going through everything - every image, every page. How can we know who this is and whether they are doing any harm? Is this abuse? Should we report this? If yes, to whom should we report it? Thank you.

Comment: This specific IP address is owned by Amazon as [whois](https://who.is/whois-ip/ip-address/47.128.16.39) shows. Is it involved in malicious activity - impossible to say based on your unclear claim of *"has been going through everything"*. As for checking the reputation of the IP see  [Who sells IP reputation data sets?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8123/who-sells-ip-reputation-data-sets)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Over 100 scanner requests 5 min after domain registration](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/190109/over-100-scanner-requests-5-min-after-domain-registration)

Comment: It's not clear that this is abuse. Only you can define what abuse is. And is it a problem that it is "going through everything"? Have they broken authentication? Is it just a searchbot?

Comment: Thank you all! Your responses have been very helpful.